# Entity Framework Core : one-to-many relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Currently working on some learning in Entity Framework Core and would appreciate some help as I've been stuck for a decent while.

I've got a set of Models:

- Users (Usernames, emails, names, etc)
- Students (Each student has a one-one relationship with a user, this is just for readability)

This is the part that is stumping me:

- School - Each school has ONE admin (user), a name and a collection/list of classes.
- School Class - Has ONE teacher (user) and a collection/list of students.

The issue I have is how do I set these models up and create a new one without having to pass a whole user object into the class/school during creation? E.g. my model might look like

```cs
class School 
{
    [Required]
    public string id {get; set;} 

    [Required]
    public User Admin {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public List<Student> Students {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public List<SchoolClass> Classes {get; set;}
}
```

(Note this is just quickly thrown together for the sake of the question)

I can provide more detail if asked but I feel my whole current approach is slightly wrong.

Essentially whenever I add a user I should be able to add a student (optional), then I should be able to create schools but ideally I don't want to have to fetch/pass in a whole user object / list of classes when initially creating a school -> I'd just like to pass in the ID of a user to be the admin for example.

Then when I create a `SchoolClass`, it shouldn't need to create new users, I should just be able to add current users. Not entirely sure where to go with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it nullable with the null operator (?)

`public User? Admin {get; set;}`

When you do your database calls, you'll add the Admin User object to the School object. However, it will not add the entire object to the database. It will only update the foreign key in the School table, and the Admin will not be marked for modification unless you explicitly do so.

Also be aware that attributes are gradually being phased out in favor of Fluent API.